# Couchbase: Is it possible to only invoke "SELECT" queries on the "master" node?

Tags: couchbase

I am having several race conditions in my app where I was able to "SELECT" a document that was previously deleted by another thread 1-2 secs ago. I added ScanConsistency.REQUEST_PLUS to my "SELECTs" but it takes too long...

I am planning to add PersistTo.ONE param to the "DELETEs" however, I am not sure if the succeeding "SELECT" will still see the deleted document or not because I think that it might invoke "SELECT" on one of the non-master nodes which still has the deleted document in-memory.

Will it be possible to "SELECT" only on the master node?

I could use PersistTo.FOUR but I think that would also affect performance greatly.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could tell from reading the documentation on this feature (this is a fairly recent addition to Couchbase), the fact that the edit takes place on another thread is significant. Each thread is going to have to have its own session with the database, and the consistency level *could* in theory be pulled from that thread, but you would need to have that thread communicate with your thread (probably a non-starter).

Therefore, going back to basics, it's important to realize that the database itself is an *eventually-consistent* data store.  This means that, given the [CAP-theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem), the data store sacrifices *consistency* for *availability* and *partition tolerance*. This is true in all cases, but the N1QL mechanism attempts to compensate a little bit for "your own writes." Being a software architect myself, I would not depend upon this except if I needed it as a temporary workaround, but rather keep the prevailing design principles in mind when designing the application data store.

Bottom line is that I believe this behavior is expected, and your design should be tolerant of it. If your application requires immediate consistency across sessions, then you should use a different data store.